# Show a Fragment all over activity/fragment with a button click

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment

i have an activity with a toolbar, a tablayout and a pager.
So with the toolbar i have the name of the app and maybe i can add some button for navigation.

With the tablayout i can click or just move the finger left or right to navigate throw my 3 fragment.

In a fragment i put a button, and it purposes is to show a fragment over all my layout. So everything i said before will be all covered by this fragment.

How can i realize that? I saw many videos and guide, but my button wont work. I dont even get any error and my app start well.
While testing, if i click the button nothing happened. In the "run" doesnt show any information, like the button is empty.

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.button2:
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), CheckActivity.class));
            getActivity().finish();
            break;

        case R.id.button3:
            EditProfileFragment editprofiele = new EditProfileFragment();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.MainAct, editprofiele).commit();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }


}
```

I have two button. The button2 is for disconnect and open a new activity.
The button3 is for showing up my fragment. I tried any combination. Maybe not replace but add, and something else. But everything isnt working.

In the activity that holds everythings i have already implements the listener to that fragment. any help?

Comment: Can u update full code for onclick event of button? How did you call onClick(v) method.

Comment: Are you using AppCompatActivity/FragmentActivity or Activity?

Answer (score 1):

onButtonClick open fragment...My button is on fragment was having same issue.

```
            AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
            YourFragment yourFragment = new YourFragment();
            activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frameLayoutMaps, myFragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .attach(myFragment)
                        .commit();
```

add frameLayout in your Activity

```
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayoutMaps"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>
```

in MainLayout of YourFragment in xml add  `android:clickable="true"`

Hope this helps.